# Click on Table Row - Select Checkbox

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an angular app, where I created a table. Here is an excerpt of the table

```
<li class="row list-table-row" *ngFor="let satz of detailSatz">
     <div class="list-table-cell col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 sel_box">
     <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="satz.selected" (change)="checkIfAllSelected();"></label>
</div>
```

My goal is, that the correct checkbox is "selected" (checked), when I click anywhere in the table row and not only when I click the "select" Button. How can I do that?

Comment: Bind `click` event on `li` and set `satz.selected=true`

Comment: Nice - quick and easy :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you have used two-way data binding with `[(ngModel)]` so any change to bonded property `satz.selected` will affect the checkbox

```
    <li class="row list-table-row" 
     *ngFor="let satz of detailSatz" 
     (click)="satz.selected">
         <div class="list-table-cell col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 sel_box">
             <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="satz.selected"
                 (change)="checkIfAllSelected();">
               </label>
           </div>
     </li>
```